# How do I re-enable windows partition after moving drives?

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, windows-7

I realize the general idea has been answered many times before. My trouble it that my situation seems too specific to address as a Google search.

I have a windows 7 based drive (150GB) that was running fine on the laptop and a larger drive (500GB). I wanted to have a full Ubuntu system so I swapped drives and installed Ubuntu on the 500GB drive. Everything was peachy till the dreaded "I want to play World of Warcraft" coming from my wife. Sigh.

So I craftily use Gparted to shrink the last partition down enough to fit the 150GB partition and then copied it over bit for bit (`dd`).

I had to stop here because I honestly don't know what to do next. How do I enable Grub2 to see the windows partition and how do I boot into windows? What are the next steps of is this kind of thing not possible with the current setup?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I myself answered the same question for about ten times. But no problem: I'll answer again!

After you install Ubuntu, you have to update GRUB (Ubuntu's boot manager) so it will recognize all the OSs in your HD. For this, open a terminal emulator (Ctrl+Alt+T) and run the following command:

```
sudo update-grub
```

Insert your password (it will not be showed) and press ENTER. Wait for the process to end. When it's done, restart your PC and Windows should be a GRUB menu entry

Comment: Thank you for the answer I'll try just that. Curious though, there isn't some magic boot bit that needs to be set and then some windows boot loader to manage? Grub can point to a partition and windows is happy? If so I'm surprised as things have gotten much better then they used to be.

Comment: No. GRUB simply recognizes all existing (and bootable) OSs.